# GreaseMonkey - Modify variable during execution

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I'm trying, for a few days now, to modify a variable during a script's execution.

The HTML page has a script tag, which calls a JavaScript file :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

We have something like this in the JS file :

```
/*File's beggining*/
val = 1;
if (val == 1) { window.open('getout.html', '_self');}
...
/*File's ending*/
```

I would like to modify `val`'s value to avoid redirection.
I've been searching for a few days; but I'm stuck. If someone can give me a hint, it would be very nice !

Thank you for reading !

Comment: remove a ")"  from window.open('getout.html', '_self');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is run your script before any of the page's scripts run, and declare `val` as an un-assignable property of the global object `window` with [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty):

```
// ==UserScript==
// ...
// @run-at document-start
// ==/UserScript==

Object.defineProperty(window, 'val', { value: 0 });
```

Subsequent assignments to global variable `val` will have no effects.

```
val = true;
console.log(val); // => 0
```

And it still works and doesn't throw if the variable gets redeclared at the same scope with `var`.

That's assuming the code you posted is in the global scope. If it isn't, then there's no way to override that value from your script. In that case I'd try another avenue and directly override the `window.open` function.